# Jupyter Notebook in Anaconda Not Loading

Tags: python-3.x, dll, anaconda

Whenever I try to open Jupyter Notebook from the Anaconda GUI (or conda terminal), I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\loops\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 10, in 
import sqlite3
File "C:\Users\loops\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\sqlite3\__init__.py", line 23, in 
from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
File "C:\Users\loops\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\sqlite3\dbapi2.py", line 27, in 
from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\loops\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in 
from notebook.notebookapp import main
File "C:\Users\loops\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 86, in 
from .services.sessions.sessionmanager import SessionManager
File "C:\Users\loops\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 13, in 
from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite3
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pysqlite2'
```

I've gone so far as to uninstall Python, uninstall Anaconda, remove all python related path variables, and reinstall Anaconda with Python.  This still has not worked.  Is there any way to resolve this error? I've looked on many different sites but I haven't found much help.

EDIT: To add more context, it broke randomly one day and I don't have the slightest idea why.  Anaconda had worked for a year or so prior.  I checked both scripts that are referenced in the error prompt and they both exist in the directory.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem.
The issue seems to arise from the missing of sqlite3.dll in the path ".\Anaconda\Dlls".(if using an env, you should put it under the env directory like ".\your env\DLLS") I solved it by simply copying that .dll file from others and put it under the path mentioned above.

You can download the sqlite3.dll from this link: [sqlite3.dll](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html)